# What is the Alternative for springfox

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi.git

Only disabled the SpringFox dependencies, added SpringDoc, and replaced the SpringFox bean, with a SpringDoc bean. Everything is working as expected. All I need to do is to convert a couple of annotations on each rest service so SpringDoc displays everything correctly. SpringDoc does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Springdoc openapi is latest alternative for springfox, as springfox is not comparable with spring boot 2.2.0 and spring hateos

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RabiAPI/Evalon4J

This is a command line tool for generating java restful api documentation,

The best point is it's using pure static analysis, no need to compile or build your project first.

Supported frameworks

- Spring MVC
- JAX-RS
- Swagger 2.0 Annotations
- OpenAPI 3.0 Annotations
- JSR303 Bean Validation

Now it can export your api to markdown format.